# Serializing / Deserializing image to / from XElement

Tags: c#, serialization, xelement

I am trying to serialize image into XElement and afterwards deserialize it for further use.
I am using this method to serialize:

```
public XElement subElement = new XElement("Element");
private void Serialize(System.Windows.Forms.Button button) {
    if (button.Image != null) {
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, button.Image);
        var textWriter = new StringWriter();
        var writer = new XmlTextWriter(textWriter);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        writer.WriteBase64(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        subElement.Add(new XAttribute("Image", imageBytes));
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to deserialize. I tried something like this:

```
private void Deserialize(XElement element) {
    if (element.Attribute("Image") != null) {
        //tried XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(element.Attribute("Image").Value));
        //but reader is empty
        //when I try: XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(element.Attribute("Image").Value);
        //exception is thrown because XmlReader expects path, not element
    }
}
```

I basically only need to get byte array from XElement, later I know how to handle it.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but would a simple `element.Attribute("Image").Value.ToCharArray().Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray()` do it?

Comment: @George Duckett Good idea, but I am only getting 13 bytes, and original is over 400.

Comment: @Vale If you open up the XML file what to you get in the Image attribute? When writing to the XML file you might want to use on of the classes in System.Text.Encoding to convert to a string from the byte array, then do the opposite when reading from it. I think the problem you have is if a 0 byte is written it'll treat that as the end.

Comment: You could also try using Convert.(To/From)Base64String instead of your XmlTextWriter's methods

Comment: Yes... I was serializing it wrong also. In xml I have this: Image="System.Byte[]". Can you briefly explain me how to do the process?

Comment: Once you have your byte array you can do Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray). The result of that function (a string) is what goes in the XAttribute's value. Then when it comes to reading, you'd just do `byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(element.Attribute("Image").Value)`

Comment: Also, i'd be tempted to test it without saving to XML at all. e.g. turn the byte array into a string, then create a new byte array from that string. Then compare the 2 byte arrays to ensure they're identical. Once you've got that then you know that any issues you have will be relating to having the string within an xml file.

Comment: @George Duckett Thank you very much. That worked. You can post your comment as answer now so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your byte array you can do `Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)`. The result of that function (a string) is what goes in the XAttribute's value.

Then when it comes to reading, you'd just do `byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(element.Attribute("Image").Value)`

This should prevent the issues with saving the string within the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use serialization, simple save/load it from memory stream.

Comment: I have to serialize it. It is very big project, this is just short version of what I need. I can only get data from xml in which i am serializing controls... It's a long story :)

Comment: I'm speaking about the image. Dont serialize the image, save the image with Save(...) method from Image class.